# how can i know how much order is placed of a product?

Tags: magento

I want to know how much orders are placed for a product. For this I'd like to use the following code but it does not give any output:

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
 $order_detail=$order->setStoreId($storeId)->getCollection()- >addAttributeToFilter('product_id',$product_id);
 print_r($order_detail);
```

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make it work, you need to use the model Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item and not Mage_Sales_Model_Order:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
$order_detail = $order->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $product_id)
//->load(); // if you don't use $order_detail->getItems() below uncomment it

foreach ($order_detail->getItems() as $order){
    echo $order->getId();
    echo '<br>';
}
```